# Best way to support wildcard search on a large dictionary?

Tags: search, dictionary, wildcard

I am working on a project to search in a large dictionary (100k~1m words). The dictionary items look like {key,value,freq}. Myy task is the development of an incremental search algoritm to support exact match, prefix match and wildcard match. The results should be ordered by freq.

For example:
  the dictionary looks like

```
key1=a,value1=v1,freq1=4
key2=ab,value2=v2,freq2=2
key3=abc,value3=v3 freq3=1
key4=abcd,value4=v4,freq4=3
```

when a user types 'a', return v1,v4,v2,v3
   when a user types 'a?c', return v4,v3

Now my best choice is a suffix tree represented by DAWG data struct, but this method does not support wildcard matches effectively.

Any suggestion?

Comment: As a new user, don't be offended but be informed that you do yourself disservice by writing in sms style. Clear punctuation and capitalization makes a question much more readable and attracts more people to give an answer. As the faq reads: *In order to get good answers, you have to put some effort into the question.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at n-grams for indexing your content. If you want to something Out-of-the box, you might want to look at [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) which does a lot of the hard work for you. It also supports prefix, wildcard queries etc.